# R : Time gap in API queries

Tags: r, shiny

I am running multiple API queries in my shiny dashboard. When I run these API queries individually, they are running fine on my system. But when I run my shiny application, it's throwing errors after first few API queries. 
Is there a way through which I can insert some time gap between two consecutive API queries. I think by this I'll able to run my application successfully.

Comment: Maybe have a look at `Sys.sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Got it :)

Comment: You should also disable any buttons that are used to query the data until data is available as users may press the button many times, which will cause the app to carry out those queries. look into `shinyjs` for this

Answer (score 0):

Inserted Sys.Sleep(2) between my API queries since the limit was 1 query per second. 
Now queries are running fine.